# EPPlus & Data Comparison

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am running a C# project with EPPlus libraries , I need it to check cells for data in various columns/rows and then find "keywords" so to speak and match it to data found in other various columns/rows.

I need to know a method for comparing data in a cell with data from another cell and finding a match.

The user selects an excel workbook & sheet through the gui , then runs this

Loop for checking cell data.

```
Variables.rowCount = Variables.worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;

for (i = 1; i <= Variables.rowCount; i++)
{
    Variables.cellValue = Variables.worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Text;
    Variables.cellValue1 = Variables.worksheet1.Cells[i, 1].Text;
    //...
```

Essentially I need it to do what Excel does when you select a filter and choose contains "word".

I hope I have explained this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this example:

`if (worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString().Contains("word"))`

this gets the value of the cell and compares it with the search string

Comment: This looks good , Do you know if it is possible to search for a combination of letters in a string, for eg if (worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString().Contains(worksheet1.Cells[i, 1]);  // and in worksheet.Cells [i.1] was a string  "GSDG MOTOR 123hsdg " how would i make it only search for MOTOR. Sorry if this is confusing , having a hard time describing it..

Comment: split your search string with `string.split()`, after that you can use your splited word for searching